# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: analysis, integration

> Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at every point, and that $f'(x)$ is continuous.
>
> 1) Prove that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 \left(f'(x)f(y)-f(x)f'(y)\right)^2 \ dx \right) \ dy \geq 0$
>
> 2) Hence prove that $2\displaystyle\int_0^1 f'(t)^2 dt \int_0^1 f(t)^2 \ dt \geq \dfrac{1}{2} \left(f(1)^2 - f(0)^2 \right)^2$

Ok, so I've done 1) quite easily using the fact that since the inside integral is a square, this implies that the integral is $\geq 0$ then using the same theorem this implies that the outside integral also gives something $\geq 0$.

Now, in regards to 2) I've tried doing this a number of ways but it doesn't seem to fall out properly. Clearly the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus needs to be used at some point but every way I've tried doing it doesn't actually help. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $2\int_0^1 f'(t)^2\,dt\int_0^1 f(t)^2\,dt\ge 2(\int_0^1 f(t)f'(t)\,dt)^2=\frac{1}{2}(\int_0^1 (f(t)^2)'\,dt)^2=\frac{1}{2}(f(1)^2-f(0)^2)^2$ where I have used that $(f(t)^2)'=2f(t)f'(t)$.

Note that if you don't want to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, you can use 1) and write $0\le \int_0^1(\int_0^1(f'(x)f(y)-f(x)f'(y))^2\,dx)\,dy=\int_0^1(\int_0^1 f'(x)^2f(y)^2+f(x)^2f'(y)^2-2f'(x)f(x)f'(y)f(y)\,dx)\,dy\implies 2\int_0^1 f'(x)f(x)\,dx\int_0^1 f'(y)f(y)\,dy\le2\int_0^1\int_0^1 f'(x)^2f(y)^2\,dx\,dy=2\int_0^1 f'(x)^2\,dx\int_0^1 f(y)^2\,dy$

this gives $\frac{1}{2}(\int_0^1 (f(x)^2)'\,dx)^2\le \int_0^1 f'(t)^2\,dt\int_0^1 f(t)^2\,dt$, or using the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\frac{1}{2}(f(1)^2-f(0)^2)^2\le \int_0^1 f'(t)^2\,dt\int_0^1 f(t)^2\,dt$.